# List available artifacts from repo with gradle, ivy or other

Tags: maven, dependencies, gradle, resolution, ivy

I'm looking for a way to list all available artifacts programmatically for given repo url, group and artifact. The repo is maven-based.

I know about maven-metadata.xml but the repo that is in use doesn't provide classifier details which are crucial for me.

Solution may be based on ivy, gradle or other compatible tools. If anybody has an idea please let mi know :)

I hope to find a code sample that will allow me to browse repo in an easy and friendly way.

Comment: What exactly do you need? The artifact paths for all available versions?

Comment: I need to get available versions for group, artifact and a classifier. The problem is that classifier isn't specified in maven-metadata.xml file. I need all available versions (1.8.8) for group (com.utest) artifact (apphance-preprod) and classifier armv7. Here's the link to my repo: https://dev.polidea.pl/artifactory/libs-releases-local/com/utest/apphance-preprod/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for all hints. Yesterday I've managed to solve the problem using artifactory REST search API and parsing the incoming JSON respones. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Use the search features of your Maven repository manager.

If you're using Nexus, it supports searches of it's [Lucene index](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-indexer-lucene-plugin/default/docs/index.html). For example the following URL returns all the artifacts matching the string "log4j":

- https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/lucene/search?q=log4j

The response is verbose but includes information like classfiers (which is what you're looking for)

Answer (score 1):

`maven-metdata.xml` only has module information, and classifier belongs to artifact (not module). Gradle is probably not a good fit here. I'd consider a low-level approach with some GET requests and HTML parsing. In case the repository is backed by a repository manager such as Artifactory and Nexus, their REST API might also be an option.